# iOS 11 Home Screen app sending wrong Cookie

Tags: ios, cookies, safari

Since iOS 11 one of our web-apps has been acting up, but *only* when added to the Home Screen as an app.

It allows for offline viewing of documents, cached using an ApplicationCache manifest, for the users selected language.

The problem is arising when users are choosing a new language.

We're persisting the language token (ie, en_GB, or de_DE) to a cookie using document.cookie, we then tell the appcache to look for updates. The server looks at the language token in the cookie and sends down a language-specific cache.manifest file.

This is the JS when the user changes their language

```
function setLanguage(chosenLanguage) {
 //...
 this.setCookie("language", chosenLanguage, 10);
 window.applicationCache.update();
}
```

*this.setCookie* uses *document.cookie* to change the cookie value, with the expiry time in days.

This works fine on desktop, and on mobile, even on iOS 11 safari.

Except in Home Screen App mode on iOS 11.

By setting a unique ID each time the cookie updates, we can look in the Web Inspector console to check the unique ids set at each point and compare them to what's being recieved by the server.

We've discovered that the Home Screen app is sending up the the cookie that was created in *Safari*. Not the one that was created using document.cookie in the Home screen App. That cookie is never sent up with any of our requests.

Not only that, but if we go back into the Safari browser version and change the language, then swap back to the Home Screen App, it sends up the updated safari cookie with the new language, but reading from document.cookie still shows the data we previously set in the app.

What I want to know is: Has anyone else had this problem and does anyone know a fix for it?

Comment: Yes, I believe I am having the same problem.  If I load my app in safari and as a home screen app, I find that all requests from safari are accompanied by the safari cookie.  However, when using the home screen app, all requests have the home screen cookie except for the manifest file.  When the home screen app requests the manifest, it always sends the safari cookie, or no cookie, if there isn't one in safari.  I'm also looking for a solution.  I hope Apple can fix this bug.